# Insert two new rows in 2d array

Tags: c, arrays, realloc

guys :) I have a 2d dynamic array and I need to find the biggest and the smallest number in every column. I have to insert 2 new lines (for max and min) in my array but it seems that my `realloc` is not working fine. Please, tell me what I am doing wrong and how I should continue.

```
int **in(int l,int c);
void out(int l, int c, int **a);
int max_colonne(int l, int c, int **a,int *max);
int minimal_colone(int l, int c, int **a,int *minimal);

int main()
{
    int **x,*max,*minimal,l,c, i, j;
    printf("nombre de lignes: ");
    scanf("%d",&l);
    printf("nombre de colonnes: ");
    scanf("%d",&c);
    x=in(l,c);
    printf("La matrice cree.\n");
    out(l,c,x);

    for(i=0;i<c;i++){

        x[i]=(int *)realloc(x, (l+2)*sizeof(int)); }


    free(x) ;
    free(max) ;
}

int **in(int l,int c)
{
    int **t,i,j;
    t=(int **)malloc(l*sizeof(int *));

    for(i=0;i<l;i++)
        t[i]=(int *)malloc(c*sizeof(int));

    for(i=0;i<l;i++)
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        {         printf("el[%d][%d]:",i,j);
            scanf("%d",(t[i]+j));
        }
    return t;
}

void out(int l, int c, int **a)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<l;i++)
    {  for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        printf("%3d",*(a[i]+j));
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int max_colonne(int l, int c, int **a,int *max)
{
    int i,j;
    for(j=0;j<c;j++,max++)
    {           *max=*a[j];
        for(i=0;i<l;i++)
            if(*(a[j]+i) > *max) *max=*(a[j]+i);
    } return *max;
}

int minimal_colone(int l, int c, int **a,int *minimal)
{
    int i,j;
    for(j=0;j<c;j++,minimal++)
    {           *minimal=*(a[0]+j);
        for(i=0;i<c;i++)
            if(*(a[i]+j) < *minimal) *minimal=*(a[i]+j);
    } return *minimal;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working fine? You get an error? Wrong result? Something else?

Comment: You are looping over `x[]` using the `c`, but you created it using `l`. Have a break ... ;-)

Comment: And it might also help cleaning up your code in terms of indenting it properly: Less noise, better awareness ...

Comment: @alk and please more whitespace, why are people afraid of using whitespaces if the compiler ignores them anyway and the make the code so more readable.

Comment: @iharob: I simply press `Ctrl-Shift-F` and it looks nice.

Answer (score 1):

Your `realloc` is not working because it's wrong, instead of

```
x[i]=(int *)realloc(x, (l+2)*sizeof(int));
```

it should be

```
x[i] = realloc(x[i], (l + 2) * sizeof(int));
```

and also, you don't need to cast to `int *`.

You should always check for the return value of `malloc`/`realloc`/`calloc` functions, on failure they return `NULL`, so to safely use `realloc` you should use a temporary variable, to prevent loosing the original pointer, since if you do this

```
x[i] = realloc(x[i], newSize);
```

and `realloc` returns `NULL` then you lost the rerference to the original pointer `x[i]` so I would recommend

```
void *tmp;

tmp = realloc(x[i], newSize);
if (tmp == NULL)
    handleMallocFailureErrorProbablyRetryOrExitTheProgram();
x[0] = tmp;
```

so for example, you can `free(x[i])` in `handleMallocFailureErrorProbablyRetryOrExitTheProgram()`.